# setTimeout not executing on chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm stuck with this javascript code; it's not executiong the timeout !!
even when I click any link it's notworking proprely.
I'm using chrome : Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 12.04

can any one help me please !!!

these is the hole code i'm using 
and by the way my jquery version is 1.11.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html data-wf-site="53314860dc25c5ac0a0001b9">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tactutalities - Administration</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="generator" content="Webflow"> 

<!-- CSS Librairy -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/webflow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/tactualities.webflow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/semantic.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/map.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/Control.Loading.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/L.Control.Sidebar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/leaflet.fusesearch.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/pace/pace.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/Control.MiniMap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/jqueryui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/l.geosearch.css"/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://y7v4p6k4.ssl.hwcdn.net/placeholder/favicon.ico">

<!-- jQuery Librairy -->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/jqueryui.js"></script>  


<!-- Application JS Librairy -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/application.js"></script>               
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/validation.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/ajaxRequest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/webfont.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/tools.js"></script>

<!-- Map JS Librairy -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="/public/js/map/leaflet.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/fuse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/leaflet.fusesearch.js"></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='/public/js/map/pace.js'></script>    
<script type='text/javascript' src='/public/js/map/countries.geo.json'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/public/js/map/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/public/js/map/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/Control.MiniMap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/geoSearch/l.control.geosearch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/map/geoSearch/l.geosearch.provider.google.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

      var j = jQuery.noConflict();
/** 
* disable double click 
**/
console=console || {};
console.log=console.log || {};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).on('click', function(event) { 
var target = event.target;
if (target.tagName==='A' || target.tagName==='IMG' || target.tagName==='BUTTON' ) {
if ( jQuery(target).data("clicked") )  {
console.log('Target',target.tagName,' Already Clicked');
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
console.log("double click event disabled");
return false;
} else {
console.log('Target',target.tagName,' not Clicked yet');
jQuery(target).data("clicked", true);
jQuery(target).prop('disabled', true);
jQuery(target).addClass("clicked");

setTimeout(function() 
{
jQuery(target).data("clicked", false);  
jQuery(target).prop('disabled', false);
jQuery(target).removeClass("clicked");
console.log('You can click Again!');
}, 5000); // Do something after 5000 millisecondes  
return true;
}
} else {
console.log('Target ',target.tagName,' will not trigger any actions');

}

});

});

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting into the `if` statements? Do remember that strings are case-sensitive :)

Comment: How far is your script getting before 'failing'? Does the 'clicked' class get applied to the target? Try adding a debugger line into your code at keys points.

Comment: Yes, @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen - the elements might be <a> not <A>!

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen: yes i'm getting inside if statement and the target.prop("tagName") === 'A' return A for link element !!

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote part of your script to

```
/** 
* disable double click 
**/
console=console || {};
console.log=console.log || {};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).on('click', function(event) { 

    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var target = jQuery(targetElement);

    if (targetElement.tagName==='A' || targetElement.tagName==='IMG' || targetElement.tagName==='BUTTON' ) {

        if ( target.data("clicked") ) 
        {
            console.log('Target',targetElement.tagName,' already Clicked');
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("double click event disabled");

            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Target',targetElement.tagName,' not Clicked yet. We will disable it now');
            target.data("clicked", true);
            target.prop('disabled', true);
            target.addClass("clicked");

            setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    target.data("clicked", false);  
                    target.prop('disabled', false);
                    target.removeClass("clicked");
                    console.log("ok, you can click again");
                }, 5000); // Do something after 5000 millisecondes  
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Target was a ',targetElement.tagName,' will not trigger any actions');

    }

    });

});
```

Please see it in action

http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/6j38r/

Comment: You're right and I'm sorry. I missed that part when I rewrote the function to use jQuery's event delegation instead of document.addEventListener. I edited my answer

Comment: thanks for the reply but still not working, when i click on some link it didn't execute the setTimeout function ??

Comment: it's working on the js fiddle yes, but not on my machine and i don't know why ???

Comment: Can you paste your whole code? You could be using an old version of jQuery, or something.

Comment: here part of what i'm using :

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/effects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/application.js"></script>               
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/validation.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/ajaxRequest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/webfont.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/tools.js"></script>

Comment: I updated my original post so you can take a look to what i'm using as js library

Comment: That's a lot of libraries to include. Enough to raise an entanglement of unmet dependencies. However, what does it say in the console? Are any events detected prior to setTimeout not firing?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the console !! i tried to debug the code with chrome and I noticed that when it ame to setTimeout chrome doesn't execute the function ?? nothing in printed in the console ??